# gVim maximized with a gray line like status line

Tags: 11.04, gvim

When I maximize gVim, at the bottom of the window i see about 20 pixels of gray line. To the right there is just 4 pixels of the same gray from top to bottom.
I had the same gray before 11.04, but at least twice smaller and didn't bother to fix it or ask about it.

A small note is that even that i use gVim my options are like console. I.e. without menu and scrollers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***VIM computes the width and height of its display area using columns and lines, not pixels***. Resize your GVIM window using your mouse, and you will notice the change.

Let's say the titlebar's height is 40px; when maximized, the width and height of GVIM window is 1024 X 722. Then, the total display area of VIM SHOULD be 1024 X 682 (722 - 40).

If the height of each line is 20px and each character (column) takes 5px, then there will be 51 (1024 / 20) lines and 4 (1024 mod 20) pixels, 136 (682 / 5) columns and 2 (682 mod 5) pixels.

***The actual width and height of VIM's display area is 1020 X 720 while the resolution of the GVIM window is 1024 X 722, this making the rest area unused (the gray area).***

How to fix it?

Never maximize the GVIM window, or you can use this trick:

```
:set lines=8888
:set columns=8888
```